"I'm someone who collects tiny things" vs "I'm someone who collect tiny things"
"I'm someone who collects tiny things"
"I'm someone who collect tiny things"
Which is correct?
I collect, yet someone collects...
It's really confusing to me. Thanks!

Do you know why it is "I am" but "He is" ?

Ahh asking a question for a question

@JamesK Why is it  "I am" but "He is" ?

Compare:  You are a cat who has nine lives.

This question is similar to: What's the verb form when use "I am" with "Who" restrictive clause?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@TheReturningDog  yes,  asking for clarification.   Do you know why it is "I am" but "He is"?  How you answer that question will change how I will answer your question.


I'm [someone who collects tiny things].

I've added the brackets for clarity.
(Edit: The relative clause has antecedent someone.)
As the entire bracketed part applies to the subject, there's no practical difference in the meaning of the sentence whether we say the relative clause has the subject or the subject complement as its antecedent.

three reasons:

Verb forms for singular pronouns: It is "I collect" because in English in the event the subject is I, you, we, or they (all pronouns that are either first-person, second-person, or plural), the verb stays in its base form without an "s". i.e. "I collect", "You collect", "We collect", "You all collect". This does not apply to any other singular nouns. I and you are the only exceptions to the rule of using a verb without s at the end when a singular pronoun is used. Pronouns such as "he", "she", and "it" take verbs with "s".
Relative clause structure: "Who collects tiny things" is a relative clause that describes "someone."; thus, the subject doing the action is now "someone" and no longer "I".
Subject-verb agreement: It's always required that the verb matches the subject in number (singular or plural) and person (first, second, third). "Someone" is a singular noun, so we need a singular verb form: "collects" instead of "collect." In English, we say "someone who collects" for a singular person, just as we would say "people who collect" for a plural subject.


Why the downvote? This looks very good to me.
